# XUnit: how to provide rich diff for Assert.Equal

Tags: xunit

How do I make Assert.Equal produce a diff-like (the unix tool) report of what is different between two objects?

In my case, I have bunch of POCO classes which define both .Equal() and .ToString() methods. My current approach is:

```
public static class MyAssert {
    public static void Equal(o1, o2) {
        Assert.True(o1.Equals(o2), MyDiff.Compare(o1.ToString(), o2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Where MyDiff.Compare compare lines using Minimum Edit Distance algorithm.

Is there a more xUnit idiomatic form?